# What do designers have to know about Twitter Bootstrap 4?

Tags: layout

I know this topic is not solid coding topic related but I still want to pull this out.

What do designers have to know about Twitter Bootstrap 4? http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

Are there any information you can share what each designer must know or research on this new release of Bootstrap?

Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: I'm not sure I would go as far as "have to know". It's a web UI/UX CSS framework and there others out there as well (Pure, Foundation, Kube, etc.). I would say a good (web) designer should be aware of CSS frameworks but beyond that depends on their project needs and requirements - and ultimately they'll need to do the research to decide which, if any, framework to use.

Comment: Graphic Design is not for "solid coding" topics.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 you can have more great features and flexibility:

There are a ton of major changes to Bootstrap and it’s impossible to cover them all in detail here, so here are some of our favorite highlights:

- **Moved from Less to Sass**. Bootstrap now compiles faster than ever thanks to Libsass, and we join an increasingly large community of Sass developers.
- **Improved grid system.** We’ve added a new grid tier to better target mobile devices and completely overhauled our semantic mixins.
- **Opt-in flexbox support is here.** The future is now—switch a boolean variable and recompile your CSS to take advantage of a flexbox-based grid system and components.
- **Dropped wells, thumbnails, and panels for cards.** Cards are a brand new component to Bootstrap, but they’ll feel super familiar as they do nearly everything wells, thumbnails, and panels did, only better.
- **Consolidated all our HTML resets into a new module, Reboot.** Reboot steps in where Normalize.css stops, giving you more opinionated resets like box-sizing: border-box, margin tweaks, and more all in a single Sass file.

And so more.. [Click here to know full details about Bootstrap 4](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Default Colors used for the links, buttons, error, status, success etc.(are modifiable yet..)
2. That it is a responsive design.
3. It is based on 12 grid system.
4. The Default margin and padding.
5. That it provides custom popups (modal) and tooltips.

That is all comes to mind. [More Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

**EDIT:** [Bootstrap 4](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/) is coming soon, so you should look at it as well.

Comment: In your answer the document you have linked is Bootstrap current version which is v3.3.5 showing its CSS features. It does not have concern with new features of Bootstrap 4.

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/
In this link you can see the What's new section for more detail knowledge of Bootstrap features.